# For loops in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am using a batch file to convert data type of many climate files (*.nc). I used a for loop to iterate through the files. However, for some reason, it does not work properly.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off

for /l %%x in (2071,1,2100) do (
pause
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s prec=float(prec) Prec_Order_%%x.nc Prec_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Tavg=float(Tavg) Tavg_Order_%%x.nc Tavg_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Tmax=float(Tmax) Tmax_Order_%%x.nc Tmax_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Tmin=float(Tmin) Tmin_Order_%%x.nc Tmin_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Wspd=float(Wspd) Wspd_Order_%%x.nc Wspd_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Srad=float(Srad) Srad_Order_%%x.nc Srad_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Hspec=float(Hspec) Hspec_Order_%%x.nc  Hspec_Order_F_%%x.nc
    )

pause
```

The program does not work to the first pause. I've checked carefully, but cannot find out where the problem is in the line "for /l %%x in (2071,1,2100) do (".

Comment: I guess you need to escape all the `)` in the `ncap2` command lines, that is, to precede each of them with `^`; for the `(`, no such thing should be required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, the first closing parenthesis `)` in the `ncap2` command line is interpreted as the closing parenthesis of the entire `for /L` loop, and so your code fails.

To overcome this, you need to escape all the closing `)` in the loop body. Escaping in `cmd` means to precede the characters by `^`. The opening `(` do not need to be escaped but it does no harm either; I prefer to do it for cosmetical reasons mainly (so one can easily distinguish them from functional `(`).

Here is the fixed code:

```
for /l %%x in (2071,1,2100) do (
    pause
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s prec=float^(prec^) Prec_Order_%%x.nc Prec_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Tavg=float^(Tavg^) Tavg_Order_%%x.nc Tavg_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Tmax=float^(Tmax^) Tmax_Order_%%x.nc Tmax_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Tmin=float^(Tmin^) Tmin_Order_%%x.nc Tmin_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Wspd=float^(Wspd^) Wspd_Order_%%x.nc Wspd_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Srad=float^(Srad^) Srad_Order_%%x.nc Srad_Order_F_%%x.nc
    C:\NCO\ncap2 -s Hspec=float^(Hspec^) Hspec_Order_%%x.nc  Hspec_Order_F_%%x.nc
)
pause
```

Comment: I voted up both of the answers as they both work well. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the best way to write `for` loops is to call a subroutine, as in the example below. This avoids all parenthesis problems.

```
for /L %%x in (2071,1,2100) do call :sp1 %%x
echo "done"
pause
goto :eof

:sp1
set arg=%1
echo arg = %arg%
C:\NCO\ncap2 -s prec=float(prec) Prec_Order_%arg%.nc Prec_Order_F_%arg%.nc
...
goto :eof
```

Comment: Is a good work around if you are not concerned about speed. The script will run faster without the CALL and just escaping the right parentheses.

Comment: @Squashman Well, if you are concerned about speed, you don't go for bat files... And from my experience, the overhead from subroutine calls is not noticeable.

Comment: Really depends on what you are doing. BAT files can be very efficient depending on the task they are accomplishing. Things like reading large files can be very inefficient.